# JHipster: Disabling liquibase - Can I disable liquibase for my project but still have the Jhipster generated tables(User, UserAuthority) be populated

Tags: jhipster

So for our use case all of our custom entity's already exist in the database. We dont want liquibase to handle any changes/updates to the entities in the database. I know this can be achieved by using liquibase.enabled: false in the yml file for the relevant profile. We will be using a hibernate setting to not start the app if the mappings to the database table arent correct.

However we would still like the JHipster generated classes for User/Authority/etc to be generated. Jhipster handles this with liquibase. I know on 1st application run up I can run with liquibase enabled and then from then on run with liquibase disabled?
Is there a better workflow for this I could do through configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can run Liquibase as a command line tool. In my project, we modified our `pom.xml` so that the build generates both the app jar and a zip of the Liquibase migrations, both artifacts are deployed to a Nexus repository and our deployment process (based on Ansible) executes Liquibase on unzipped migrations retrieved from the Nexus repo.

In addition, you can also use [Liquibase contexts](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html) to restrict some migrations to some environments only: e.g to init admin password only in dev or test.